# How to stop Locust Load Test after all users complete their task?

Tags: locust

In locust documentation, we can only stop task using self.interrupt() but it will move to parent class. It will not stop load test. I want to stop complete load test after all users login and complete their task

Locust Version: 1.1

```python
class RegisteredUser(User):
    @task
    class Forum(TaskSet):
        @task(5)
        def view_thread(self):
            pass

        @task(1)
        def stop(self):
            self.interrupt()

    @task
    def frontpage(self):
        pass
```

Comment: DId you find any solution for this?

Answer (score 5):

You can call `self.environment.runner.quit()` to stop the whole run.

More info: https://docs.locust.io/en/stable/writing-a-locustfile.html#environment-attribute

Comment: I want to run for 10 users and i am expecting to complete 10 tasks for those 10 users. Now i want to stop locust after all tasks are completed for all 10 users. How can I achieve this?

Comment: You can do it with locust-plugin’s -i parameter: https://github.com/SvenskaSpel/locust-plugins#command-line-options

Answer (score 1):

My framework creates a list of tuples of the credentials and support variables for every user. I have stored all my user credentials, tokens, support file names etc in those tuples as part of list. (Actually that is automatically done before starting locust)

I import that list in locustfile

```
# creds is created before running locust file and can be stored outside or part of locust # file
creds = [('demo_user1', 'pass1', 'lnla'),
         ('demo_user2', 'pass2', 'taam9'),
         ('demo_user3', 'pass3', 'wevee'),
         ('demo_user4', 'pass4', 'avwew')]

class RegisteredUser(SequentialTaskSet)

    def on_start(self):
        self.credentials = creds.pop()

    @task
    def task_one_name(self):
        task_one_commands

    @task
    def task_two_name(self):
        task_two_commands

    @task
    def stop(self):
        if len(creds) == 0:
            self.user.environment.reached_end = True
            self.user.environment.runner.quit()


class ApiUser(HttpUser):
    tasks = [RegisteredUser]
    host = 'hosturl'
```

I use self.credentials in tasks
I created **stop** function in my class

Also, observe that **RegisteredUser** is inherited from **SequentialTaskSet** to run all tasks in sequence.